# While adding two float values am getting wrong output in java

Tags: java, floating-point, decimal, addition

In java while add the float number a and b getting wrong output.

```
Float a = 39.97757f;
Float b = 59.96636f;

System.out.println(a+b);
```

getting output as 99.943924 instead of 99.94393

Comment: `Float` (uppercase F) and `float` (lowercase f) are not the same thing.  You should not use objects when you only need numbers.  (But it has nothing to do with floating point precision.)